# Query in Sqlite to remove blob duplication

Tags: sql, sqlite, blob

I need to run a Delete query to remove any rows from a table where there is duplication for a specific blob column

can I rely on the size of the blob in order to validate it?

any suggestions how to archive this?

Table example:

```
ID int
TheName varchar(50)
Content Blob
```

Comment: The simple answer is "No".  However, you need to include your table structure and some example of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite handles blobs like any other field, so you can use comparisons or `GROUP BY` on the `Content` column.

To find duplicate records, you can group all identical blobs together, and check the count of the records in each group; then get one ID from each of those groups:

```
SELECT max(ID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Content
HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

Using this as a subquery, you can actually delete those records:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT max(ID)
             FROM MyTable
             GROUP BY Content
             HAVING count(*) >= 2)
```

(If there are triplicates or more, you'll have to execute this multiple times.)

Comment: You can do it in one go if you use WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT min(ID) FROM myTable GROUP BY Content) (omitting the HAVING, of course).

Comment: it seems nice, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more column (lets call it ContentHash) with Blob's hashes (you can use SHA256 or md5). Then using new column you can easily identify duplicates and delete them.

Using Blob size is very unreliable way, you can delete different posts with the same content size. If it is acceptable then use it )

Answer (score 0):

1. use SELECT DISTINCT and fetch all records into temporary table.
2. truncate first table.
3. Select all records from temp table to first table.